# error getting while installing perl modules using cpanel from my web site

Tags: apache, apache2, cpanel

Recently i have buyed a new site www.infibox.in   actually i am trying to install perl modules from my cpanel but i am getting the following error

```
Testing connection speed...(using fast method)....Done
Ping:0 (ticks) Testing connection speed to perlmirror.indialinks.com using pureperl...(cached .. 58600.00 bytes/s)...Done
Ping:5 (ticks) Testing connection speed to cpan.mirror.choon.net using pureperl...(cached .. 9233.33 bytes/s)...Done
Ping:7 (ticks) Testing connection speed to cpan.biz.net.id using pureperl...(cached .. 7587.50 bytes/s)...Done
Ping:6 (ticks) Testing connection speed to cpan.cermin.lipi.go.id using pureperl...(cached .. 7387.50 bytes/s)...Done
Ping:8 (ticks) Testing connection speed to ftp.cuhk.edu.hk using pureperl...(cached .. 6377.78 bytes/s)...Done
Five usable mirrors located
Ping:23 (ticks) Testing connection speed to 208.74.125.42 using pureperl...(using cached speed)...Done
Ping:21 (ticks) Testing connection speed to 66.23.237.210 using pureperl...(using cached speed)...Done
Ping:24 (ticks) Testing connection speed to 69.72.212.10 using pureperl...(using cached speed)...Done
Three usable fallback mirrors located
Mirror Check passed for perlmirror.indialinks.com (/index.html)
Checking C compiler....Could not locate an executable "cc" binary....Done
 ** Unrecoverable Error **
The C compiler is not functional and auto repair failed.
Perl module installs require a working C compiler.
Please repair the C compiler and try again.
 **************************
```

But i try to upload the modules to my directory /home/guolaujk/perl/usr/local

but i can not execute system modules and getting the following error

Can't locate loadable object for module Crypt::DH::GMP in @INC (@INC contains: /home/guolaujk/perl/usr/local /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i686-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at /home/guolaujk/perl/usr/local/Net/OpenID/Common.pm line 39.

but actually i inclued this module in /home/guolaujk/perl/usr/local directory.

please provide any solution for it..

Answer (score 0):

Some perl modules have advanced functionality that requires compilation.

To me this looks like the issue -

> Checking C compiler....Could not locate an executable "cc" binary....Done

The c compiler is either not installed, or it's location is not in the Path, **or it's restricted to a priveledged user**.

See the CPanel Compiler Access guide for this -

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/DisableCompilers